# Controlling VirtualBox via COM from Python?

Tags: python, com, virtualbox

I'm trying to control latest Sun VirtualBox via it's COM interface from Python. But, unfortunately, the following code don't work:

```
import win32com.client
VBOX_GUID = "{B1A7A4F2-47B9-4A1E-82B2-07CCD5323C3F}"
try :
  oVbox = win32com.client.Dispatch( VBOX_GUID )
  oVbox.FindMachine( "kubuntu" )
except Exception as oEx:
  print str( oEx )
```

Error is general "(-2147467262, 'No such interface supported', None, None)"
It seems that the wrong part is my COM handing via Python. Anyone can drop a look and suggest some obvious thing i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't virtualbox support mozilla's XPCOM but not m$' COM?

Comment: just an unrelated suggestion, don't catch every exception as you did, that makes hard to find errors. The default traceback behavior you get if you don't add that try/except is much more useful.

Comment: it's just to illustrate a problem, test code

Comment: Ping!  Have you seen my answer?

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks. That was the problem. I have also contacted VBox developers and they have confirmed that current OLE Automation support is incomplete - not all classes have IDIspatch. They have stated that in a few months new version will be released that will fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the object returned by `FindMachine("kubuntu")` does not support the `IDispatch interface`, and win32com does not support that.

You could use my `comtypes` package http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes/ for that, but you need to patch the version in the repository to make it work with the VirtualBox type libraries.

Here's a demo session:

```
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from comtypes.client import CreateObject
>>> box = CreateObject("VirtualBox.VirtualBox")
>>> m = box.FindMachine("Fedora")
>>> print m.State
4
>>> print m.CpuCount
1
>>> print m.Name
Fedora
>>>
```

And here is the patch that you need:

```
Index: automation.py
===================================================================
--- automation.py   (revision 507)
+++ automation.py   (working copy)
@@ -753,6 +753,8 @@
     c_float: VT_R4,
     c_double: VT_R8,

+    c_ulonglong: VT_I8,
+
     VARIANT_BOOL: VT_BOOL,

     BSTR: VT_BSTR,
```

Comment: FYI: With comtypes version 0.6.1 the patch is no longer needed.